# A Question after Decades of Struggle

Tags: grammar, articles, singular-vs-plural

**India attained independence in 1947, after decades of struggle.**

I had nothing to do with the Indian independence, but I looked up the word **struggle** online and it came out to be countable. Should there be an article before the word **struggle**, or should the word be plural in that sentence? You know, a countable noun is always dependent on an article or s or es or ies.

Comment: 'Struggle' can be countable **or** uncountable, as it is in your example.

Comment: I really appreciate your reply. I am not familiar with the plural and uncountable stuff and dictionaries don't always help when they hardly provide all definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, many popular dictionaries do list this as only "countable", yet this is a clear example of uncountable usage.

Macmillian [does list this uncountable sense](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/struggle_2):

> COUNTABLE/UNCOUNTABLE a fight, or a war
>
> There was a brief struggle, then a shot was fired.
> a group involved in armed struggle against the government

The second example illustrates the uncountable sense.

The uncountable use is less common and trivially derived from the countable meaning. Your sentence could have been rephrased with a *plural*  "...after decades of struggles..."